# Hubot hangs/freezes when launching

Tags: irc, hubot

I am able to get Hubot to work when running in the command line.  However, when I try and connect it to a grove.io it seems to 'hang' or 'freeze'.  I get just two lines:

```
[Fri Feb 07 2014 18:23:43 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING The HUBOT_AUTH_ADMIN environment variable not set
[Fri Feb 07 2014 18:23:44 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO Data for brain retrieved from Redis
```

Is there anything else I need to do, it seems that you don't need to 'install' anything else for the hubot-irc adapter, just set the variables.  I'm connecting to grove.io through a rackspace server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably not "the answer" But hitting enter clears that for me and drops to the prompt as I would otherwise expect. I've seen no ill effects so far.

Comment: I noticed that as well.  I had another issue that I was seeing as well and that was resolved by upgrading node to v0.11.11 (I was on V0.08.xx)